# 2 conditions 1 AND statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to exclude all data from my report that is dated before 6/1/2018 from location 170. This is what I have to work with below.

[image: Location/Date Table]

I have tried using this,

```
AND (Location <> 170 AND Last_Mdt < '2018-06-01').
```

I thought that if I had the parenthesis this would act as one AND statement where both conditions must be met but the report is excluding data before 2018-06-01 for all locations. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You should add the whole where clause. As-is, it's only speculation; for example, you might have: `WHERE 1 = 1 OR (1 = 1 [your clause])`

Comment: Oh, and be mindful of datetime: `2018-06-01 12:34:56` is not `<=` to `2018-06-01`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
AND (Location <> 170 OR Last_Mdt >= '2018-06-01')
```

Or, you might find this easier to follow;

```
AND NOT (Location = 170 AND Last_Mdt < '2018-06-01')
```

These are logically equivalent, assuming the columns do not take on `NULL` values.